# Xcode 7 to 8: Size Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I have developed an app with Xcode 7 and I placed all my views for all iPhones in portrait. Now using Xcode 8 I want update the constraints for supporting iPads in portrait. How I am supposed to to that? Copy/Paste views and start from scratch? I can't see any other solution.
PS. Note that views for iPhone 7 Plus to iPhone 4S appears fine.

Comment: copy storyboard and make new project and add in it. your constraint will remain safe. @BlackM

Comment: I want to use the same storyboard. But I added the views when I was in "iPhones in portrait mode" and they won't appear on iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of copying the views. The Xcode `SizeClasses` aids you in designing the app for various devices.

I suppose you may have used the `Any Width Any Height` (`wAny hAny`) or the `Compact Width Regular Height` (`wC hR`) to design the portrait orientation screens. Now use the `Regular Width Regular Height` (`wR hR`) size class to design the iPad screens. Size classes will automatically switch sensing the device rather than programatically selecting one among the two `storyBoard`s designed for iPhones and iPads.

Select the wR-hR size class. Select your view in the `Document Outline`in the `storyBoard`. In the `Attribute Inspector` install the view for the current size class (`wR hR`). the view will appear in the storyboard scene. Set the suitable constraints and you are good to go.

PS: Of course you must set the constraints again unless you have designed the iPhone screens in `wAny hAny` size class. If so that works in iPads too and you needn't work on any other size class.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for but I didn't noticed it because it was at the bottom!!